# Why does this query returns empty?

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, py2neo

I have a flask application using py2neo that shows groups. I am trying to make the URL more pretty, so I found these two articles: one about [how to generate slugs](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/5/) and another one on [how to create custom converters](https://exploreflask.com/views.html#custom-converters). I combined those articles to make the following code:

```py
# app/views.py

from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for
from models import graph, Group

app = Flask(__name__)

from .util import SlugConverter
app.url_map.converters['slug'] = SlugConverter

...

@app.route('/group/<slug:group_name>')
def show_group(group_name):

    query = """
    MATCH (group:Group)
    WHERE group.slug = {group_name}
    RETURN group
    """
    group = graph.cypher.execute_one(query, group_name = group_name)
    if group:
        return render_template('group.html', group = group)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('show_groups'))
```

.

```py
# app/util.py

from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter
import re
import translitcodec

class SlugConverter(BaseConverter):

    def to_python(self, value):
        pass

    def to_url(self, value):
        exp = r'[\t !"#$%&\'()*\-/<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|},.]+'
        punct_re = re.compile(exp)
        delim = u'_'
        result = []
        for word in punct_re.split(value.lower()):
            word = word.encode('translit/long')
            if word:
                result.append(word)
        return unicode(delim.join(result))
```

It has no problem in creating the slug and replacing the url. The problem I have is that if I pass the `query` through `graph.cypher.execute_one()` it returns `None`. I do not understand why. If I use the same query in the NEO4J web viewer only replacing `{group_name}` for an example, `"north_carolina"`, it returns the relevant node.

Why does this query returns empty?

Comment: Have you tried using pdb (or print) to see whether group_name is empty in the first line of show_group?

Comment: @Oin it does appear to be empty. I flashed that variable and the result is `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SlugConverter.to_python` method must return the actual value you want to use in your view. You might be able to just switch your `to_url` value to be `to_python` instead. And just make `to_url` do `return value`.